# - The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String,

Tags: java

i hav written the get method but i want to write the set method but then it gives me the error saying - The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String, )my code is given below
            package com.glomindz.mercuri.dao;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 import com.glomindz.mercuri.pojo.User;
 import com.glomindz.mercuri.util.MySingleTon;

 public class UserServicesDAO {

private Connection connection;

public UserServicesDAO() {
    // connection = new MySingleTon().getConnection();
    connection = MySingleTon.getInstance().getConnection();

}

public List<User> get_all_data() {
    List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO              spl_user_master(name,email,mobile,password,role,status,last_update)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
         stmt.setString("Charlie Sheen","help@glomindz.com","9654087107","cbf51a71a11d7ec348b0d7e9b2f0055f","admin","3","null");

        boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
            user.setMobile(resultSet.getString("mobile"));
            user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
            user.setRole(resultSet.getString("role"));
            user.setStatus(resultSet.getString("status"));
            user.setLast_udpate(resultSet.getString("last_update"));
            usersList.add(user);
        }
    } 

    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return usersList;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserServicesDAO userdao = new UserServicesDAO();
    List<User> data = userdao.get_all_data();
    System.out.println(data);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}
my user class is
         package com.glomindz.mercuri.pojo;

```
     public class User {

private int  id;

     private String  Name;

private String  email;

private String  mobile;

private String  password;

private String  role;

private String  status;

private String  last_update;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
  return Name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  Name = name;
 }

  public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
  }

  public String getMobile() {
  return mobile;
  }

  public void setMobile(String mobile) {
  this.mobile = mobile;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
  return password;
   }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }

  public String getRole() {
  return role;
  }

   public void setRole(String role) {
  this.role = role;
   }

   public String getStatus() {
  return status;
 }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
      this.status = status;
  }
  public String getLast_update() {
  return last_update;
  }



  public void setLast_udpate(String last_update) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }




     @Override
   public String toString() {
   return "User [id=" + id + "Name=" + Name + ", email=" + email + ", mobile=" + mobile
          + ", password=" + password + ", role=" + role + ", status="
          + status + ", last_update=" + last_update + "]";
    }



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[PreparedStatement.setString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) is not a variable arity method; it doesn't take variable no. of arguments. Each placeholder(**?**) must be set individualy using

```
stmt.setString(1, "Charlie Sheen");
stmt.setString(2, "help@glomindz.com");
```

and so on.

Using Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO spl_user_master(name,email,mobile,password,role,status,last_update)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", new Object[] {
         "Charlie Sheen","help@glomindz.com","9654087107","cbf51a71a11d7ec348b0d7e9b2f0055f","admin","3","null"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stmt.setString("Charlie Sheen","help@glomindz.com","9654087107","cbf51a71a11d7ec348b0d7e9b2f0055f","admin","3","null");
```

This doesn't work. You have to set this individually, something like:

```
stmt.setString(1, "Charlie Sheen);
```

Where 1 is the position of the variable and "Charlie Sheen" is the value. You need to do this for every placeholder `?` you have in your PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, You cannot set all the params at once using setString. You need to set each param using setString one by one.:

```
stmt.setString("Charlie Sheen","help@glomindz.com","9654087107","cbf51a71a11d7ec348b0d7e9b2f0055f","admin","3","null");
```

From the javadocs:

> [setString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)
>
> void setString(int parameterIndex,
>                  String x)
>                  throws SQLException
>
> Sets the designated parameter to the given Java String value. The
>   driver converts this to an SQL VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR value (depending
>   on the argument's size relative to the driver's limits on VARCHAR
>   values) when it sends it to the database.
>
> Parameters: parameterIndex - the first parameter is 1, the second is
>   2, ... x - the parameter value
>
> Throws: SQLException - if parameterIndex does not correspond to a
>   parameter marker in the SQL statement; if a database access error
>   occurs or this method is called on a closed  PreparedStatement

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) Oracle tutorial, the [`setString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method takes in an integer, representing the number of the parameter and a string, representing the value. So, in your case, you would need to do something like so:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO spl_user_master(name,email,mobile,password,role,status,last_update)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
stmt.setString(1, "Charlie Sheen");
stmt.setString(2, "help@glomindz.com");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As already posted by others , you are passing wrong parameters to the `setString()` method . Remember you have to set value to each of the place holder `?` defined in query individually .

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO
     spl_user_master(name,email,mobile,password,role,status,last_update)
     VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
stmt.setString(1,"Charlie Sheen");
stmt.setString(2,"help@glomindz.com");

     ... so on ...
```

Remember `setString()` is used to set `SQL VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR` value in place of the placeholder, if the corresponding column is defined as  `SQL VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR`. for other data types , there are various `setXXX()` methods in the API.